# Bash: "Invalid option" when run in bash script, fine on console

Tags: macos, bash

The following works on console, but throws an "invalid option" when run as part of a bash script.

```
styles=find . -type d -maxdepth 1 | awk -F/ {'print $NF'}
line x: .: -t: invalid option
```

Comment: As written, this command sources a file named `-type` with the environment variable `styles` set to the string `find`.  I strongly suspect the question is missing backticks or `$()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To save the output of a command to a variable, you need to use command substitution:

```
styles="$(find . -maxdepth 1 -type d | awk -F/ '{print $NF}')"
```

Comment: It would be more conventional to put the single quotes outside the `{` and `}`, as in `awk -F/ '{print $NF}'` than as you've written them.  In practice, there isn't a difference, but it still looks a little odd.

Comment: Nicely done; note that double-quoting the RHS in _assignments_ is optional.

Comment: @mklement0 It has become a habit :)

Comment: Got it; just wanted to point it out; there's nothing wrong with doing it, and I do see the value in double-quoting consistently, without having to struggle to remember when they're actually needed vs. when they're not.